# AutoComplete for text field

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autocomplete, uitextfield

I've been trying to create a textfield with autocomplete and cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong at this point.  When you click into the field the keyboard comes up but as you start typing it does not bring up the table view or populate the table with the array.  My code is below:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *productDescription;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *productDescriptionTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *productDescriptionArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *productDescriptionFilterArray;

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize productDescriptionArray;
@synthesize productDescription,productDescriptionTableView;
@synthesize productDescriptionFilterArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
productDescriptionArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                @"Product Description 1",
                @"Product Description 2",
                @"Product Description 3",
                @"Product Description 4",
                @"Product Description 5", nil];
    productDescriptionTableView.hidden = FALSE;
    productDescriptionTableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
    [[productDescriptionTableView layer] setMasksToBounds:NO];
    [[productDescriptionTableView layer] setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [[productDescriptionTableView layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f)];
    [[productDescriptionTableView layer] setShadowOpacity:0.3f];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - UITextField Delegate
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"Range:%@",NSStringFromRange(range));
    NSLog(@"%@",productDescription.text);
    NSString *passcode = [productDescription.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"%@",passcode);
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@",passcode];
    productDescriptionFilterArray = [productDescriptionArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"%@", productDescriptionFilterArray);
    if ([productDescriptionFilterArray count]==0)
    {
        productDescriptionTableView.hidden = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        productDescriptionTableView.hidden = FALSE;
    }
    [productDescriptionTableView reloadData];
    return TRUE;
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [productDescriptionFilterArray count];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    productDescription.text =Cell.textLabel.text;
}

@end
```

Comment: So the array contains items? And the table exists?

Comment: Yes, the array will contain static items.  I do not want the user to be able to add or delete items to the array.

Comment: At this time, when simulated, the field is treated as a standard text entry field.  It does not pull up the table and it does not autocomplete.